# Rcpp Compiler error in r tools for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: r, openmp, rcpp

I am a new user of **Rcpp** and **OpenMP**.
I have written code to multiply two arrays.
I want use omp as well just to check its performance with big matrices.

I use **R** tools in [Visual Studio 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2015) to work and run this code:

[image: This code]

When I compile it in **r tools for Visual Studio 2015**, I get this error:

```
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/MIE74D~1/ROPEN~1/R-35~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"C:/Users/amaa11/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/amaa11/DOCUME~1/VISUAL~1/Projects/RPROJE~1/RPROJE~1"   -I"C:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.5.1/vendor/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c mul_mat.cpp -o mul_mat.o
mul_mat.cpp:10:4: error: stray '#' in program
/ /#pragma omp parallel for
^
mul_mat.cpp:4:1: error: expected unqualified-id before '/' token
/ / [[Rcpp::export(mul_mat)]]<br>
^
make: *** [mul_mat.o] Error 1
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: As a first cut, try eliminating errant spaces between `//`; that is, wherever you have `/ /`, change it to `//`. Haven't yet looked farther to see if there are other problems.

Comment: Thanks it works, but it is still ignore pragma from omp.h header

Comment: That's because it's commented out; will update answer.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52566312/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick and easy answer is: Remove the space between comment forward slashes. For example, change

```
/ /#pragma omp parallel for
```

to

```
//#pragma omp parallel for
```

However, I also have other comments/tips for asking questions here in the future:

- Please don't post a picture of your code. Copy and paste it into your question. Then answerers can easily copy and paste your code to test it. I manually re-typed your code in this case to test it (so I can say with certainty this answer will solve your error), as I'm just sitting bored drinking my morning coffee, but in other situations, would honestly probably have not taken the time to re-do your typing.
- If what you're wanting is matrix multiplication, go for [`RcppArmadillo`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=RcppArmadillo)! As several answers to other questions on here have pointed out, [it's an obvious choice for matrix multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31675554/8386140) and [already uses "multi-threaded OpenBLAS as well as OpenMP"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49729369/8386140).
- Note that you don't have to initialize the elements of `mult` to 0; as stated in, for example, the [Rcpp Quick Reference Guide](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-quickref.pdf), a `NumericMatrix` constructed in a way such as `Rcpp::NumericMatrix x(n, m)` creates an n by m matrix already filled with 0.

#### Update

So, for completeness, this is the fixed code that compiled fine for me:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix mul_mat(int n, NumericMatrix A, NumericMatrix B) {
    int i, j, k;
    NumericMatrix mult(n, n);
    for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        //#pragma omp parallel for
        for ( j = 0; j < n; ++j ) {
            mult(i, j) = 0;
        }
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < n; ++j ) {
            for ( k = 0; k < n; ++k ) {
                mult(i, j) += A(i, k) * B(k, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return mult;
}
```

And we can see it exported the function to R (this part added in response to now deleted comments regarding the proper way to export the function to R):

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("so-answer.cpp")
> ls()
[1] "mul_mat"
```

You initially had a(n incorrectly typed) comment delimiter before the `#pragma omp parallel for`; if you really want to use it, remove the comment delimiter as well as add `// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]`; this is discussed (among other places) in an [Rcpp Gallery post](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/dmvnorm_arma/):

> Additionally, we can make use of the OpenMP library to use multiple
>   cores. For the OpenMP implementation, we need to enable OpenMP
>   support. One way of doing so is by adding the required compiler and
>   linker flags as follows:
>
> Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-fopenmp")
>   Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS"="-fopenmp")
>
> Rcpp version 0.10.5 and later will also provide a plugin to set these
>   variables for us:
>
> // [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]

So, try:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <omp.h>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix mul_mat(int n, NumericMatrix A, NumericMatrix B) {
    int i, j, k;
    NumericMatrix mult(n, n);
    for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        omp_set_num_threads(2); // For example
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for ( j = 0; j < n; ++j ) {
            mult(i, j) = 0;
        }
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < n; ++j ) {
            for ( k = 0; k < n; ++k ) {
                mult(i, j) += A(i, k) * B(k, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return mult;
}
```

which also compiled just fine on my machine.

Comment: It really helped me. thanks. When I compile it, it works fin. But when I add an omp function such as omp_set_dynamic(0); and compile it, I got same error which is "warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma omp parallel for" and  "undefined reference to `omp_set_dynamic'". which means it does not work parallel.

Comment: @ahmedabdo Thanks, I was focusing on whether the given code would compile, I forgot about a detail you'll need to when you actually use OpenMP. About to update.

Comment: @ahmedabdo Updated

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really do not know how to thank you. I really appreciate it. Now I will work on the running time with and without omp. to see the difference.

Comment: @ahmedabdo No problem, glad it helped! Don't forget to [mark the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by "click[ing] on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in" so that others know this is the solution to this issue.

Comment: I did. can recommend and web, books, article to understand omp well?

Comment: @ahmedabdo I'm not an expert on OpenMP; I've really only looked into it a little once I started using `RcppArmadillo`. One place to start would be [this web article](https://wbnicholson.wordpress.com/2014/07/10/parallelization-in-rcpp-via-openmp/) and [Rcpp Gallery posts tagged open mp](http://gallery.rcpp.org/tags/openmp/).